# Isothermal coordinates existence using Cartan geometry

Tags: riemannian-geometry, cartan-geometry

Are there proofs of the existence of such coordinates near every point of a riemaniann surface $(M,g)$ using Cartan connections and curvature ?

Here is a proof i tried to write down, but i suspect it may be wrong since i dont use complicated theory of PDEs. I write $(G,P)$ for the Euclidean Klein geometry where $G$ is the Euclidean group an $P=O_2(\mathbb{R})$. I write $(e_1,e_2,A)$ for the usual basis of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}=Lie(G)$ of the euclidean group, so $e_1,e_2$ are the infinitesimal translations and $A=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ is the usual basis of $\mathfrak{p}=Lie(P)$. The conformal Klein geometry is denoted by $(G',P')$.

1. Start from the torsionfree euclidean Cartan geometry $(E,\omega)$ corresponding to the metric
2. Extend it canonically to a conformal Cartan geometry, which means $(E',\omega')$ where $E′$ is an extension of the orthogonal principal bundle E and ω′|E=ω. In particular, the curvature function of this Cartan connection is of the form $k_{\omega'}|_E = k_\omega=fe_1^* \wedge e_2^* \otimes A$ where $A$ is the usual generator of $\mathfrak{p}=Lie(P)$ and $f$ is an $P$-invariant function on $E$.
3. Construct a new conformal Cartan connection $\omega''$ on $E'$ as follow. Denote by $e_{-1},e_{-2}$ the vectors corresponding to the opposite roots of those associated to $e_1,e_2$ (in a Chevalley basis of $\mathfrak{g}'=Lie(G')$).Then $A=[e_1,e_{-2}] = -[e_2,e_{-1}]$. So we can consider a $P'$-équivariant function $\varphi$ uniquely defined by : $$\varphi|_E = - fe_1^* \otimes (e_{-1}-e_{-2}) + f e_2^* \otimes (e_{-1}-e_{-2})  $$ which statisfies $\partial \varphi = -k_\omega$. We construct $\omega''=\omega'+ \varphi \circ \omega'$.
4. Using Bianchi identity, we have $d\varphi = 0$. In particular, the change of curvature between $\omega'$ and $\omega''$ is $\partial \varphi$, so $\omega''$ is a flat conformal Cartan connection on $E'$.
5. $(E',\omega'')$ admits a developpement $\psi : U\longrightarrow G'/P'$ near every point $x\in M$. On a neighboorhood of $\psi(x)$ there exist a flat metric $g_0$, so $g'= \psi^\star g_0$ is a flat metric on a neighboorhood of $x$. By construction, this metric is in the conformal class of $g|_U$.

Do you detect a problem with this proof ?

Thank you

Comment: This is too vague. Could you say more about the approach you have in mind?

Comment: This result is a theorem in PDEs. You can restate it using Cartan geometry, but this is just a reformulation.

Comment: @Deane : I have written a proof using only Cartan connections and extension principle from the euclidean model to the conformal model, but i suspect it may be wrong beacause the only PDE is used implictly when i use developpements of a flat Cartan geometry.

Comment: @Moishe Kohan : Do you have a precise reference in mind ?

Comment: @AG14 Your work in comments should be included in your question

Comment: I moved my blabla to the question body. Thank you.

Comment: @AG14 It is called the Beltrami equation. One can think of it also as integrability of the almost complex structure for complex 1-dimensional manifolds.

Comment: Thank you. How does it answer to the question? I'm sorry i cant see.

Comment: I don't have the time to go through the proof carefully, but my guess is that one of the steps implicitly uses the Beltrami equation. One thing to watch out for is that you might have applied a lamma that does not require solving a PDE for real differential forms but does for complex differential forms.

Comment: In fact step 4 is false because i used a wrong formula of Lie Cartan for 2-forms. So $\varphi$ is not the section  giving a flat Cartan connection in general. We have to consider a $C^\infty$ combination of the two terms in its sum so that the alternation of $ d\varphi$ vanishes. PDEs appear just here.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of $\varphi$ in the question doesn't lead to a flat conformal geometry.

However, since we can consider a general section $\varphi = a e_1^* \otimes e_{-1} - b e_2^* \otimes e_{-2}$ (where $a,b$ are $P'$-invariant differentiable functions on $E'$) to construct a general conformal Cartan connection $\omega''$ from $\omega'$, without torsion.

Let's consider the parabolic decomposition $\mathfrak{g}'=\mathfrak{g}_1 \oplus \mathfrak{g}'_0 \oplus \mathfrak{g}'_{-1}$ of $\mathfrak{g}'$ (where $\mathfrak{g}'_0 \oplus \mathfrak{g}'_{-1} = \mathfrak{p}$). If we want $\omega''$ to be flat, then by looking at the $\mathfrak{g}'_0$-component of the new curvature, we must have : $a+b = -f$. So $a=-fc$ and $b=-f(1-c)$ for a differentiable function $c$ on $E'$.

The PDE appears when we look at the $\mathfrak{g}'_{-1}$-component of the new curvature. Let's denote by $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ the $\omega'$-constant vector fields associated with $e_1$ and $e_2$. The condition is that : $$\mathcal{L}_{Y_1}(a) + \mathcal{L}_{{Y}_2}(b) = \mathcal{L}_{Y_1}(fc) + \mathcal{L}_{Y_2}(f(1-c))=0$$ Since $c$ and $f$ are the pullback of diffrentiable functions on $M$, this can be rewritten into a PDE over the base manifold by considering exponential coordinates.

It looks like a Beltrami equation but i can't put it concretly into this form.